# SwiftUI: How to dismiss a View after Firebase Firestore document changes?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

TLDR: How do I dismiss the current View presented by a `NavigationLink` when its `userId` is no longer in the array anymore.

I am trying to create a "kick out" feature for the owner to kick other users. Still, after setting up a listener for any changes on a Space document, I am not sure how to call `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` for users whose ID is not in Space's array anymore.

### SpaceView

```
    struct SpaceView: View {
        
        @ObservedObject var spaceViewModel: SpaceViewModel
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                VStack(spacing: 15) {
                    membersCollectionView
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 40)
                moreActionSheetView
            }
        }
        
        //MARK: - Views
        var membersCollectionView: some View {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(
                    columns: spaceViewModel.memberColumns,
                    alignment: .leading,
                    spacing: 16,
                    pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders, .sectionFooters]
                ) {
                    ForEach(spaceViewModel.space.members, id: \.self) { member in
                        SpaceMemberCell(member: member, action: spaceViewModel.spaceMemberCellTapped(_:))
                    }
                }
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
            }
        }
    }
```

### SpaceViewModel

```
    class SpaceViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var space: Space
        
        @Published var showAddFriendsActionSheet = false
        @Published var showMoreButton: Bool = true
        @Published var showMusicButton: Bool = false
        @Published var showAddFriendsButton: Bool = true
        @Published var showRaiseHandButton: Bool = false
        @Published var showMuteButton: Bool = false
        @Published var memberColumns: [GridItem] = []
        @Published var selectedMember: SpaceMember?
        @Published var accessType: SpaceAccessType = .member
        @Published var memberActionSheetOffset: CGFloat = 0
        @Published var moreActionSheetOffset: CGFloat = 0
        @Published private(set) var isAllMuted: Bool
        //@Published private(set) var roomStatus: Space.RoomStatus
        private var spaceListener: ListenerRegistration!
        @Published var isKickedOut = false
        
        init(space: Space) {
            self.space = space
            self.isAllMuted = space.isAllMuted
            self.roomStatus = space.roomStatus
            self.memberColumns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(100), spacing: 16), count: space.members.count)
            setAccessType()
        }
        
        deinit {
            removeListeners()
        }
        
        ///initializer for personal/solo space
        init(personalSpace: Space) {
            self.space = personalSpace
            self.isAllMuted = personalSpace.isAllMuted
            self.roomStatus = personalSpace.roomStatus
            setAccessType()
            self.showMuteButton = false
        }
        
        func removeListeners() {
            if spaceListener != nil {
                spaceListener.remove()
            }
        }
        
        func setAccessType(){
            guard let userId = Customer.current?.userId else { return }
            if space.owner.memberInfo.userId == userId {
                accessType = .owner
            } else if space.speakerIds.contains(where: { $0 == userId }) { //check if current user is one of the speakerIds
                accessType = .speaker
            }
            switch accessType {
            case .owner:
                showMusicButton = true
                showRaiseHandButton = false
                showMuteButton = true
                
            case .speaker:
                showRaiseHandButton = true
                showMuteButton = true
                showMusicButton = false
                
            case .member:
                showRaiseHandButton = true
                showMuteButton = false
                showMusicButton = false
            }
        }
        
        func updateIsAllMuted(shouldMute: Bool) {
            let newSpace = space
            isAllMuted = shouldMute
            SpaceService.updateIsAllMuted(isAllMuted: shouldMute, spaceId: space.spaceId)
            newSpace.updateIsAllMuted(shouldMute)
            space = newSpace
        }
        
        func startSpaceListener() {
            spaceListener = db.collection(CollectionKeys.spaces)
                .document(space.spaceId)
                .addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error on space listener \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        self.handleError(title: "Error fetching space", message: error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    guard let snapshot = snapshot,
                          let newSpace = Space(document: snapshot)
                    else {
                        print("Failed to create a space in listener")
                        return
                    }
                    self.space = newSpace
                    let memberIds = newSpace.members.map({$0.userId})
                    if !memberIds.contains(Customer.current!.userId) {
                        **//kick out user here or something**
                    }
                })
        }
        
        func spaceMemberCellTapped(_ member: SpaceMember) {
            selectedMember = member
            memberActionSheetOffset = 0
        }

        func removeFromSpace() {
            guard let member = selectedMember else { return }
            SpaceService.removeMember(member: member, spaceId: space.spaceId) { (alertError) in
                if let alertError = alertError {
                    print("Error toggling space status \(alertError)")
                    //self.handleAlertError(alertError: alertError)
                    return
                }
                self.space.removeMember(member: member)
            }
            selectedMember = nil
            memberActionSheetOffset = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        }
    }
```

In `SpaceViewModel`'s `startSpaceListener()`, I want to dismiss `SpaceView` if the user's userId is not in the space list anymore. `Space`, `SpaceMember`, and `SpaceOwner` are nothing but a simple class without any decorator.

I don't think it is necessary, but I can provide the model's code upon request.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `isKickedOut` to `true` inside

```
    if !memberIds.contains(Customer.current!.userId) {
        isKickedOut = true 
    }
```

Then in this part

```
    ForEach(spaceViewModel.space.members, id: \.self) { member in
                        SpaceMemberCell(member: member, action: spaceViewModel.spaceMemberCellTapped(_:))
}
```

check if `spaceViewModel.isKickedOut` is `false` and only in this case return `SpaceMemberCell`s

like:

```
    if !spaceViewModel.isKickedOut {
        ForEach(spaceViewModel.space.members, id: \.self) { member in
                            SpaceMemberCell(member: member, action: spaceViewModel.spaceMemberCellTapped(_:))
    }
 }
```

Comment: sorry but I was looking to dismiss the SpaceView which was displayed by the previous view using a NavigationLink thats why I want to somehow call presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

Comment: In swift UI we are using declarative approach to build user interface so, you need to declare when you are showing SpaceView in the previous view and if this condition is not true just not show it anymore. In this case I don't think that using imperative dismiss is right thing to do ...

Comment: I'll keep that in mind but I am struggling to understand on how I can do that.I am currently using a ```NavigationLink(destination: SpaceView(space: space), isActive: showSpaceView){ EmptyView() }``` to present the SpaceView with animation. Not sure how can SpaceView make showSpaceView = false